# AWS RDS Role type: Master vs Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When creating a new MySQL RDS instance, named *app-dbid*, the role type says `master`

[image]

When creating a MySQL RDS instance that is from the snapshot of *app-dbid*, naming it *app2-dbid*, the role type says `Instance`.

[image]

I was curious what these terms mean, and what the ramifications are of deleting the "master" *app-dbid* but keeping the *app2-dbid* instance

Comment: did you ever get clarity on this? I have the same question